# Raspberry Pi Live Stream + Image Capture

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, streaming-video

I'm wanting to set up a camera using a PI. This camera will capture images of vehicle registration plates when motion is detected, to be checked and validated.

Is it possible to both live stream and capture an image when motion is detected?

Raspberry PI 3
Camera Module
PIR motion sensor

Answer (score 0):

I have used Motion - https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion - for a similar use case. It captures a picture every x second, with motion detection to start the capture if you want. There is a small server avaiable which exposes a live stream on a port, the "stream" itself is stored in a directory, but not as video but as many single pictures. So you can extract any still image from the target directory, and have the stream avaiable via the server.